# Why can't I access R.layout and R.id from CustomListAdapter function getView?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class TrajectoryListAdapter(
    context: Context,
    @LayoutRes private val layoutResource: Int,
    private val trajectories: List<Trajectory>
) : ArrayAdapter<Trajectory>(context, layoutResource, trajectories) {


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var leView = convertView

        if (leView == null) leView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.table_listview, parent, false)
        (leView!!.findViewById(R.id.tvTime) as TextView).text = getItem(position)!!.t.toString()
//        (convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.tvX) as TextView).text = getItem(position)!!.x.toString()
//        (convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.tvY) as TextView).text = getItem(position)!!.y.toString()
        var tvT :TextView = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.tvTime)

        return leView!!
//        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent)
    }

    private fun createViewFromResource(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view: TextView = convertView as TextView? ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false) as TextView
        view.text = trajectories[position].t.toString()
        return view
    }
}
```

In this code, `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.table_listview, parent, false)` Android Studio says `R.layout.table_listview` is an unresolved reference. Also the same later for `R.id.tvTime`.

From `MainActivity.kt` I can access them. Where is the problem?
Aim of this Adapter is to make `ListView` with three columns, each with one `TextView`.

Comment: Is the error for `R` or for 'tanle_listview`? Look at which part is underlined. Check your imports.

Comment: `R.layout` is white font, so it's good. but the `table_view` part is red - errored

Comment: Check to make sure you didn’t import the wrong R class at the top of your file.

Comment: yes, i had to remove `import android.R` thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong import that ide autoimported itself had to be removed.

remove `import android.R`